# val() from textarea not selecting searched terms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

The following var is only working in my script when the text is hard coded in the textarea (e.g. London):

script

```
var thought = $('textarea[name=search]').val(); //...used in object literal
```

html

```
<textarea rows="5" name="search" type="text" id="term">London</textarea>
```

I'd like to be able to type a search term into the textarea and search for it but it's not working?

---

I've tried all of the answers below with no luck!? I've therefore included the following in the object literal. It pulls the hard coded value from the textarea (like before) but it doesn't pull a value that is typed in the textarea normally? I thought this might be easier to resolve the problem (the feed not working when the search term is typed in)

```
search: $('textarea[name=search]').val(),
```

I'm following this tutorial below for a twitter feed with jquery but adding a textarea to search for terms,topics,hashtags etc is proving difficult to figure out.

[Twitter Feed with Jquery linky](http://www.queness.com/post/14004/easiest-way-to-retrieve-twitter-timeline-and-hashtags-twitter-oauth-api-11)

Comment: You should listen to the `change` \ `keyup`... event in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Do with `keyup` or `change` event of textarea

```
$("textarea[name='search']").keyup(function(e){

var currentText=this.value;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options, either search using a `click` event on some button called Search, or use a `change` / `keyup` event to grab the new value each time the field is updated, and perform the search that way:

```
$("#term").keyup(function() {
    console.log(this.value); //theres your value!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, if you use it like this, it will be stored in the thought var and you can call it from whatever function you're using.

Since your method calls it one time probably before you edit it.
At least that is what I'm guessing since your code is obviously not complete ;).

```
var thought = '';    
$('textarea[name=search]').keyUp(function(){
    thought = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add jquery and use below code.

```
<html>
<head>
//import jquery here
<script>
$(document)
    .on("click", "#btn", function(event) {
var thought = $('textarea[name=search]').val();
alert(thought);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea rows="5" name="search" type="text" id="term"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click me">
</body>
```